# How do I delete either the first or last set of rows in a dynamic fashion

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to delete the first 100 rows or the last 100 rows in a certain table (ordered by the primary key).

Note: Lots of data is being spooled into this table.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY the field DESC|ASC limit 100
```

Answer (score 16):

for first 100,

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY <field> ASC limit 100
```

and for last 100,

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY <field> DESC limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @first = 1;
delete from mytable 
where primKey in (select 1 
                  from myTable 
                  order by 
                    CASE WHEN @first = 1 THEN primKey END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @first <> 1 THEN primKey END DESC
                  limit 100)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure mysql don't allow limit in inner queries.

Comment: @ItayMoav, I'm pretty sure of the opposite.

Comment: @Johan we are both wrong, I should have stated the versions where this restriction holds (5.1 and below, if my memory serves) and you have to do the same. If you believe 5.1 supports that, you are more than welcome to test this.

Comment: @ItayMoav, a quote from the 5.0(!) manual page: `If LIMIT occurs within a subquery and also is applied in the outer query, the outermost LIMIT takes precedence. For example, the following statement produces two rows, not one:

(SELECT ... LIMIT 1) LIMIT 2;`, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @Johan You do not have to prove anything to me, just try it for yourself, the error message is pretty clear.