# Deleting Specified Number of Top Rows from Database (Java SQL)

Tags: mysql, database, delete-row

I have a table PRI in database and I just realized that I have entered wrong data in the first 100 rows so I want to delete them. Now I don't have anything to ORDER the rows, so how should I go about the deletion process?

Comment: You have invented a new syntax for mysql...thus it doesnt work...if you would have searched on SO you would have found the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete either the first or last set of rows in a dynamic fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754931/how-do-i-delete-either-the-first-or-last-set-of-rows-in-a-dynamic-fashion)

Comment: @bub Is it because I didn't use WHERE in the delete statement?

Comment: you see the error, don't you? There is nothing in mysql called `TOP(n)`

Comment: @fujy The commands in that question did not help me, I dont have anything using which I can Order my values because the Primary Key is of Text type

Comment: @bub I found this on the internet: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/delete_top.php

Comment: ok   but SQL Server <> mysql

Comment: So no @fujy, this question is not a duplicate because I dont have anything to use for ORDER BY.

Comment: The TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return not delete the record

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with top, now can you suggest to me how I can actually go about the deletion?

Answer (score 0):

If `TOP` is an actual keyword, you are on the wrong DBMS. Else you have to read again on how to delete rows.

Generel tip:

If you mess up, use an external DB tool (SQLDeveloper, HeidiSQL, etc.) and connect to your database. Do your clean up until your have a sane database state again.

**Then** continue coding. Not before. Never use code to undo your failures.

Comment: This doesn't provide any answer to OP's question. Please use comments for vague statements. Once you have enough reputation you can comment.