# ORDER BY gives incorrect syntax when trying to delete records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to **delete 14 records** from my table and getting an error that says

> incorect syntax near the keyword 'order'

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8754931/7849709) with no luck and have searched almost everywhere for a fix to this simple but i cant get the right solution. Please help.

```
DELETE FROM
  MeterReading
ORDER BY
  id ASC
limit
  14
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBll3.png)

Comment: limit is not valid syntax for sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. `limit` is not  valid in SQL Server.

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 14 *
    FROM MeterReading
    ORDER BY id
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you find it useful, you can always upvote/accept. Just saying  :)

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I did not see your answer the time i posted mine. No offence. :)

Answer (score 3):

i think you need below

```
   with t1 as
     (
     select top 14 * from t FROM MeterReading 
      order by id ASC         
     ) delete from t1
```

`limit` is mysql syntax so you have to remove that

Comment: You need the `ORDER BY` in the CTE *(Who downvoted, and why?)*

Comment: @MatBailie edited

Answer (score 1):

`SQL Server` has `TOP (n)` clause so, use instead of `LIMIT` clause:

```
DELETE 
FROM MeterReading m
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP (14) id FROM MeterReading ORDER BY id ASC);
```

However, you can also do :

```
DELETE mr
FROM (SELECT TOP (14) mr.id 
      FROM MeterReading mr
      ORDER BY mr.id
     ) mr;
```

Comment: this also does the job thank you

Comment: @MartinSmith. . . Suddenly internet has stopped. so edit paused.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM MeterReading where ID in (select top 14 id from MeterReading ORDER BY id)

Comment: `DELETE T FROM (select top 14 id from MeterReading ORDER BY id) T` will be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

The solution you were looking at was written for mySQL not SQL Server,

to delete in SQL Server you use

```
Delete From TableName WHERE yourcondition
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
This is the right way.

`DELETE FROM MeterReading
   SELECT TOP 14 *
   FROM MeterReading 
   ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: No, that's a syntax error.